# Redirect to HTTPS with .htaccess for several domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite, https

I have several websites that share an htaccess file (Drupal multisite), and would like to redirect several of them to the https version of the sites. I saw [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835453/redirect-to-https-with-htaccess-with-a-specific-domain/41089395#41089395) for one domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^specific\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I'd like to modify it to work for several domains, but am not sure whether I can do the following, or whether the lines need to be re-written:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^specific\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^another\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I didn't want to try it, in case I blow up several live sites.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 options:

1. Just redirect all the domains:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
   ```
2. Or target specific subdomains using `[OR]` clause:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^specific\.com [NC,OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^another\.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
   ```