# htacces, how to combine whole domain redirection to secure connection and controler/action capturing?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

How to combine the following rules ?
the rule to redirect whole domain, and the rule to capture controller/action to $_GET ?

according http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/ssl/how-to-force-https-using-the-htaccess-file , but not working for me

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somedomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.somedomain.com/$1 [R]
```

or  according 
[Redirect to HTTPS with .htaccess with a specific domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835453/redirect-to-https-with-htaccess-with-a-specific-domain) , but not working for me

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somedomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

and the rule to capture controller/action to $_GET['url']

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Working redirect, with action/controller capturing to $_GET['url']

```
RewriteEngine on

IndexIgnore * 
RewriteBase /public

#redirects somedomain.biz to https://www.somedom.biz
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somedomain\.biz [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

#redirects www.somedomain.biz to https://www.somedomain.biz
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.somedomain\.biz [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

#captures controler/action?parameters to $_GET['url']
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^index.php?(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Flags - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

L means last

R - redirect

QSL - By default, the first (left-most) question mark in the substitution delimits the path from the query string. Using the [QSL] flag instructs RewriteRule to instead split the two components using the last (right-most) question mark. This is useful when mapping to files that have literal question marks in their filename.

NC|nocase - Use of the [NC] flag causes the RewriteRule to be matched in a case-insensitive manner. That is, it doesn't care whether letters appear as upper-case or lower-case in the matched URI.