# htaccess - need to redirect one non https domain to https when multiple domains pointing to the same server

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Need to redirect one non https domain to https when multiple domains pointing to the same server. 
In detail, all the non www domains need to be redirected to www and only one domain need to be redirected to www as well https.

For example, domain having SSL

```
http://example.com to https://www.example.com
http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com
https://example.com to https://www.example.com
```

domain doesn't have SSL

```
http://example2.com to http://www.example2.com
http://example3.com to http://www.example3.com
```

I have tried many of the solution provided on stackoverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835453/redirect-to-https-with-htaccess-with-a-specific-domain).

My current htaccess will look like below,

```
#redirect to https - domain that having SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

#all other non www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Everything is working fine except on one scenario. When I enter domain with www `(http://www.example.com)` that is having SSL, not redirecting to https.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm actually following your requirements correctly, just add the following first:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @ArunA Specifically with what URL?

Comment: And btw, unless you want a 302 redirect for some reason, you'll want to make sure that all [R] are [R=301].