# URL-Rewriting for a specific domain out of multiple domains/website hosted on single server and using same web.config file

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7, web-config

Hi I am trying to implement https redirection for a specific domain lets say https://www.primeurl.com, whereas I have multiple websites hosted on same server using same web.config file, but i want this redirection only for my "primeurl.com" and not other domains. Is it possible? if Yes how can i write the url-rewrite code in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
     <rule name="Force HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
        <conditions>
         <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

</system.webServer>

Comment: What do you mean you have multiple websites hosted on same server using same web.config file?

Comment: I mean multiple domains pointing to same server, what is the confusion in this?

Comment: Is it possible to use primeurl as a mark for redirection, and then redirect to the URL you want. What URL do you want to redirect https://www.primeurl.com to?

Comment: Trying to redirect from http to https

Comment: You can take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835453/redirect-to-https-with-htaccess-with-a-specific-domain/11835555